# MySql - Select records like a particular number present in a string and separated by commas

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, mysql-regexp

I have a table named `product_info` containing the following data:

```
+-------------+------------+----------------+
|    title    |    slug    |     tags_id    |
+-------------+------------+----------------+
|   Maserti   |  /maserati |   10,34,7,110  |
|   Ferrari   |  /ferrari  |   10,34,7,107  |
| Rolls Royce | /rollroyce | 6,10,121,64,78 |
| Caterpillar |    /cat    |   4,8,210,214  |
|  Peterbilt  | /peterbilt |  8,100,210,214 |
+-------------+------------+----------------+
```

Next I have a string of php:

```
$tag = ['id' => 10, 'slug' => 'luxurycars', 'title' => 'LuxuryCars'];
```

I want to search my table and see if I have any records with this tag. You can see the ids of the tags are present in the `tags_id` row.

As you can see, `the id of the tag is '10'`. I have tried many queries but the result is always not what I want it to be.
For Example: I want to search for `'10'` in `tags_id` and I want it to match only `'10'` but it matches `10, 107, 110 and 210` and any numbers which resemble or have `10` in them.

What I expect is when I search for `'10'` (which is a tag named LuxuryCars), I want `Maserati, Ferrari and Rolls Royce` in result (obviously by being searched by tags_id as they have in the table)

I dont want `Peterbilt and Caterpillar` in my result just because they have a tag `210` associated to them.

Please help!
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for a single value in a comma-separated list, you can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('10', tags_id);
```

From the documentation:

> `FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`
>
> Returns a value in the range of `1` to `N` if the string `str` is in the string list `strlist` consisting of `N` substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by `,` characters.